# How to use std::string_view with reverse iterators?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdstring, string-view

I am trying to create a very simple function:

```
bool is_palidrome(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string r(s.crbegin(), s.crend());
    return s==r;
}
```

In order to avoid unnecessary allocations
I thought I could use a string_view:

```
bool is_palidrome(const std::string& s)
{
   std::string_view r(s.crbegin(), s.crend());
   return s==r;
}
```

However the last function fails to compile since the compiler cannot find a suitable constructor (I tried both g++ 12.2 and clang++ 15.0).
Why there isn't a constructor for this case while `std::string_view r(s.cbegin(), s.cend());` works perfectly? I check the standard https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view but I do not see which condition is not satisfied.

Comment: A string_view is only ever over an existing contiguous buffer. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: Mine is probably a stupid comment but if [a,b] is continuous isn't [b,a] as well?

Comment: One of the most common ways to check for a palindrome is to use a simple loop, indexing from both the beginning and the end, and compare individual characters until the indexes passes each other. It's actually going to be more effective than a comparison, because in a worst case (it's a palindrome) the comparison using `==` will compare the *whole* string, while a loop as described above will only compare *half* the string.

Comment: Regarding the [b,a] thing, that's not how computers work. The buffer needs to be contiguous in *one direction* (forward from a to b). You can't go backwards in space like that.

Comment: the full error message and command line will probably help to shed some light, it could be that there is no constructor to create a string from a string_view required by operator==

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you very much you gave me a good hint. The palindrome function was just a minimal working example to explain my problem.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You can implement `is_palandrome` without allocating.  "Using `std::string_view` with reverse iterators" is not the solution, however.

Comment: @DrewDormann No it isn't in my code I truly need to reverse a string and I thought a nice and fast to write option was with std::string_view

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- well, it will actually compare the whole string, but using only `Length / 2` iterations comparing 2-characters per-iteration `:)`

Answer (score 3):

First it is better to have argument as `std::string_view` (so literals and std::string are covered without any extra allocations).

Then you need to check only half of the range and use algoritm `std::equal` (as in other answer).

```cpp
bool is_palidrome(std::string_view s)
{
    return std::equal(begin(s), begin(s) + size(s) / 2, rbegin(s));
}
```

Note [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) allows to skip some `std::`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `std::string_view` to do this.

To implement your approach - comparing the entire string with its reverse - you can use [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal).

```
bool is_palindrome(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::equal( begin(s), end(s), rbegin(s) );
}
```

Comment: Note this code is comparing the *entire* string, when really you only need to compare *half* of the string

Comment: @RemyLebeau absolutely correct.  Marek R's answer changes what OP was attempting, and makes the function better in two ways.